# JSoup acts differently on Android than on PC?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have been porting a PC Application I made to Android. I have the code up and running perfectly, but JSoup seems to be getting the wrong data for some reason. I did a direct copy and paste from the working PC Application, which works just fine. Here is a piece of the code I am using in both PC and Android

```
        String AllGamesURL = "http://www.nfl.com/standings?category=league&season=" + Stringyear + "-REG";
        String HomeGamesURL = "http://www.nfl.com/standings?category=league&season=" + Stringyear + "-REG&split=Home";
        String AwayGamesURL = "http://www.nfl.com/standings?category=league&season=" + Stringyear + "-REG&split=Road";
        String DivisionGamesURL = "http://www.nfl.com/standings?category=league&season=" + Stringyear + "-REG&split=Division";

        Document AllGames = Jsoup.connect(AllGamesURL).get();
        Document HomeGames = Jsoup.connect(HomeGamesURL).get();
        Document AwayGames = Jsoup.connect(AwayGamesURL).get();
        Document DivisionGames = Jsoup.connect(DivisionGamesURL).get();

        Elements AllGamesTeams = AllGames.select("table.data-table1 tr.tbdy1");
        Elements HomeGamesTeams = HomeGames.select("table.data-table1 tr.tbdy1");
        Elements AwayGamesTeams = AwayGames.select("table.data-table1 tr.tbdy1");
        Elements DivisionGamesTeams = DivisionGames.select("table.data-table1 tr.tbdy1");

        for (Element teamName : AllGamesTeams) {
            if(teamName.select("td[align] > a[href]").text().trim().equals("")) {
                team = teamName.select("td[align]").text().trim();
            } else {
                team = teamName.select("td[align] > a[href]").text().trim();
            }
            if(team.equals(currentSelectedTeam)) {
                //Division = teamName.select("td:eq(2)").text().trim();
                wins = Integer.parseInt(teamName.select("td:eq(3)").text().trim());
                losses = Integer.parseInt(teamName.select("td:eq(4)").text().trim());
                ties = Integer.parseInt(teamName.select("td:eq(5)").text().trim());
                gamesPlayed = wins + losses + ties;
                pointsFor = Integer.parseInt(teamName.select("td:eq(7)").text().trim());
                pointsAgainst = Integer.parseInt(teamName.select("td:eq(8)").text().trim());
                break;
            }
        }
```

On the PC Version, it gets the wins, losses, etc just fine, but on Android, it is getting the wrong data. Any ideas?

Comment: What's "wrong" about it?

Comment: JSoup gets the right data on the PC Version, but gets the wrong data on the Android version even though the code that reads the website was a direct copy and paste from the PC Version.

Comment: You just restated your post and didn't answer my question.

Comment: As a wild guess, since you apparently haven't tried to debug this, but you are doing very detailed screen-scraping: Maybe you're getting a mobile version of the site that has a different structure.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand your question. If you are asking what it specifically does, the integers that are supposed to represent the wins and losses are showing up as 0 and they show up as the actual numbers in the PC version without any issue.

Comment: It throws an exception at losses saying it is getting ".000" instead of the actual losses.

Comment: How would I get it to scrap the desktop site then?

Comment: Okay, that's a start. Have you run a debugger on this? Are the `int`s zero because you never get into the `for` loop, perhaps because the HTML you're getting from Android doesn't have the same table structure? Start by checking whether your `for` loop is executing to narrow down where the problem is, then dump the document output from Jsoup if it's not being run.

Comment: Just ran the debugger again, it makes it into the for loop, says the wins are equal to 0, and then throws the NumberFormatException at losses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a specific userAgent when you connect to request the desktop version of the site instead of the mobile version, for example:

```
Document AllGames = Jsoup.connect(AllGamesURL)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36")
    .get();
```

To confirm, I also tried the same thing but passed in an Android userAgent instead and it retrieved different content (which is what will be happening on Android by default).

You can use the code I provided, or see a list of user agents here: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php